# SQL Order By while ignoring leading characters

Tags: sql

Im looking for some help with regards to ordering by a numeric value but the numeric values have leading chars (-).

For example
Column Order #

---5

--8

-6

A simple ORDER BY Order# DESC gives me an unordered output. How do you ignore the leading chars when sorting data such as the Order # above?

Comment: first of all, what database are we talking about ? functions differ between mysql, mssql etc... however... did you try `order by replace(columnname, '-', '')` or something to that effect ?

Comment: Should multi-digit numbers, if any, be treated like numbers, or like strings? In other words, should `"10"` be ahead or behind `"5"`?

Comment: 5 should be treated below 10.

Comment: Tuncay Göncüoğlu I tried that but it didnt work the output is still out of order

Comment: Is there always only one number? Which database? Voting to close as no where near enough information...

Comment: I have a column with leading chars, they columns data is numbers preceded by a special char for example @ or !. I need to know how to order this column by ignoring the leading chars. Is that hard to understand?

Comment: You may need to do a pass through of the data if the order by replace doesn't work. Wherever you are pulling this data in from, put it in a table variable first and remove all special characters, then use this in the same way you were using the permanent table previously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I came up with is similar to the answer given,

I can just cast the column data to an int and sort it the way ie

ORDER BY CAST((ColumnName) AS INT) DESC;

this sucessfully ignores the leading chars and sorts it by the numbers

Answer (score 0):

Using the H2 database syntax and functions, and a table declared as:

```
create table foo(bar varchar(10));
```

with the rows:

```
'---2'
'--3'
'-1'
```

the following query:

```
select bar from foo 
order by cast (replace(bar, '-') as int);
```

gives me the results:

```
BAR  
-1
---2
--3
```

which seems to be what you're after.

---

Disclaimer: this is possibly not the best way to do this, since the computed value is not indexed. For just ordering a reasonably-sized result set it doesn't matter.